# different behavior of predicates in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to understand the different behavior of predicate in and outside of a rule. when I write:

```
test(1,2).
```

in the console I get "predicate not found". 
but when I write

```
S=[test(1,2,3)],member(test(1,A,B),S).
```

prolog answers although the predicate test is still not defined. why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, `test(1,2,3)` is just a structure. In a conventional language, something like `[test(1,2,3)]` would cause the language to go and *evaluate* some *function*. Python for instance:

```
def test(x, y, z):
   return 3
```

Then `[test(1,2,3)]` would *reduce* to `[3]`.

This is **not** how Prolog works. Prolog does not have functions, it has *relations*, and relations do not have a pre-defined data flow into and out of them. To give a concrete example, consider `nth1/3`: if you call `nth1(3, [a,b,c], X)` then Prolog gives you back `X = c`, but you can also call `nth1(X, [a,b,c], c)` and Prolog gives you back `X = 3`. You can also call `nth1(X, [a,b,c], Y)` and then Prolog will give you back three solutions: `X = 1, Y = a`, `X = 2, Y = b` and `X = 3, Y = c`.

I like this example a lot because it shows you that `nth1/3` is doing all the work of Python's `enumerate()` *and* `index()` *and* `__getitem__()`. But it also shows you why Prolog cannot just evaluate predicates and replace them with what they "return."

That still leaves you with some ambiguity about what exactly `[test(1,2,3)]` means in Prolog. The answer is that it is a list containing Prolog terms. There's just one term in there, a functor or structure `test(1,2,3)`. Your second example shows that you are able to unify that structure with another structure. This is a very powerful thing that Prolog lets you do. It's part of what makes Prolog a *homoiconic* language, meaning a language that has a built-in understanding of its own constituents. For the time being, you can think of it as analogous to Javascript objects or Python dictionaries or C structures. It just happens to have the same shape as the predicate definitions. I consider this fact both a source of great power and great confusion for beginners, so take some heart! It is not intuitive, especially coming from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `test` is a predicate of arity 2 which you try to prove and that does not exist.

In your second example, `test` is a functor of arity 3. That does not define any `test` predicate. It is just a function whose inputs are the values `1`, `2`, and `3`, and whose value is `test(1,2,3)`. So, `test(1,2,3)` is the value of the function `test/3`. A constant like `a` may also be viewed as a function, it has no input, and its value is `a`.

Predicates define relations between functions.